# Change default selection color using CSS

Tags: css, selection

I know this question has a very straightforward answer which has already been provided a zillion times on this site. However, that straightforward answer doesn't seem to serve my purpose. The most commonly advised technique is this:

```
::selection {
    background: #ffcc00;
}
::-moz-selection {
    background: #ffcc00;
}
```

This is what I have got implemented on my site; it's to change the default light blue selection color to a dark yellow (**#ffcc00**). But take a look at the image below:

[image]

If you notice, only the areas with text (or some other object) are getting the yellow highlight color. Other parts are still highlighting in the default light blue color. Is there any way to ensure the color I have chosen applies to the entire page indiscriminately?

Comment: Adding a space to blank sections will probably do it - it's as it is because you can't select nothing - hacky but it should work

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
html ::selection{
  background: #000;
}
```

Comment: This didn't change anything. :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this

```
* ::selection {
    background: #ffcc00;
}
* ::-moz-selection {
    background: #ffcc00;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
::-moz-selection{
    background:#ffcc00;
    color:#000;
    }


::selection{
    background:#ffcc00;
    color:#000;
    }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing information on how and why it solves the problem improves its long-term value